# google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError solution?

Tags: google-app-engine

My appengine application often throws out this exception.
This is because appengine application is blocked in China, so I uses third party service to bypass the blocking. My application needs to call the APIs, which is in China, to fulfill the requests. I know many of you have no this problem, please for help.
I know the limit is 30 seconds.I can't let google to lengthen it.

Comment: does the API call need to be in the Web Handler? Could you move this task to a taskqueue?

Comment: when you move it to task queue, you get around 10 minutes for computation before DeadlineExceededError is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html) to do the actual request and either have the client poll for a result or use the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html).  This would increase your limit to 10 minutes instead of 30 seconds.

So, for example:

- Browser makes request via AJAX
- Server returns Channel token and kicks off Task
- Browser opens channel and waits for response
- Task provides browser response via channel