# DeadlineExceededError in GAE + BQ despite several steps taken to avoid it

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have <s>a BigQuery query that takes perhaps a minute</s> several BigQuery queries that each take around 10-30 seconds to run that I have been trying to execute from Google App Engine.  At one or more places in the call stack, an HTTP request is being killed with a `DeadlineExceededError`. Sometimes the `DeadlineExceededError` (unsure which kind) is raised as is, and sometimes it is translated to an `HTTPException`.

Following leads found in different SO posts, I have taken various steps to avoid the timeout:

- Run the query in a task that is added to a GAE TaskQueue, setting the `task_age_limit` to 10m. ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429936/google-appengine-runtime-deadlineexceedederror-solution))
- Pass a `timeoutMs` flag to `getQueryResults` (called on a job object in Google's Python API) using a value of 599 * 1000 ~ 10 minutes. ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992860/google-app-engine-task-queue-deadlineexceedederror-on-file-upload/7004676#comment36352018_7004676))
- Just before the call to `getQueryResults`, call urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60), every time, in an attempt to ensure that the setting is local to the thread that is making the call. ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051628/gae-appengine-deadlineexceedederror-deadline-exceeded-while-waiting-for-htt), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949682/how-to-solve-deadline-exceeded-error-in-localhost-google-app-engine-python), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623952/deadline-none-after-using-urlfetch-set-default-fetch-deadlinen))

A gist of the relevant part of a typical stack trace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/emwalker/ab03961f751021209ae0#file-gistfile1-txt). In a typical task execution, there will be a number of failures and then finally, perhaps, a success.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805543/deadline-exceeded-error-even-with-a-taskqueue-running-on-a-backend) seems to be saying that a `urlfetch` call will not be allowed to exceed 60 seconds on GAE, in any context (including a task). I doubt the queries are exceeding the hard limit in my case, so I'm probably missing an important step.  Has anyone run into a similar situation and figured out what was going on?

Comment: Have you considered using async queries, rather than waiting for the result.   https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asyncqueries

Comment: Yes, because the you fir off the query and then check every so often for the result set.  This means you can run very long queries.

Comment: For anything expected to be long running on BQ, you probably should run an async job, then use a queue to check whether the result is ready. UrlFetch does have a hard limit of 60 seconds, regardless of being on a backend or not.